# How to convert an iPhone app to an iPad app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios4

I am a beginner, and I have an iPhone app.

I want to convert iPhone app to iPad app.

I want to increase the size of all control, images and views according to iPad dimensions programmatically as I have no controls in XIB but in fact they are programmatically made.

I don't want to change the dimensions manually at every place because it is too much of a cumbersome work.

Is there any way I can do this in a better way?

Comment: "because it is too much of a cumbersome work". Sound like laziness to me!

Comment: BTW, what you asked for is effectively what the iPhone Native loader on the iPad does... (just not as good res)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The simple answer is NO**.

You have to do it manually. There is no automatic system.

That is the correct answer.

if you have an absolutely trivial app - ie, with no images or controls or layouts! - you can of course just change it to an iPad app.

The questioner **is asking specifically** how to change all the images, layouts, and so on in a normal app. The answer is it must all be done completely manually. There is no automatic system for re-doing design or re-doing images in Photoshop, etc.

Note that similarly if you want to do both portrait and landscape layouts of an app, you or your designers have to of course simply design both layouts. There's no, say, "artificial intelligence" system that automatically does art direction for the app! You simply have to manually design both layouts and manually build in Photoshop all necessary images for each situation. The same applies to iPad v. iPhone.

(Note that sometimes you will have to do four totally different layouts, and sets of graphics .. for the phone/pad and portrait/landscape.)

This is exactly why iPad apps are sometimes labelled "HD" in the app store - they are of course totally different.

Comment: That may have been the situation in Dec 2010 but I found it very easy to convert my iPhone app to iPad by switching it to universal in the target section.  My app was pretty simple but it worked.

Comment: @jroyce, your comment is not relevant and quite confusing for new users. you should delete it !

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode, click on your project on the "Groups & Files" sidebar. Press command-I. Search for Targeted Device Family and change it from iPhone to iPad. Then it will compile and run on an iPad but the UI might look a bit funky.

What I did after that was open the xib I used for my iPhone app's FlipSide view (the one that looks funky on the iPad) go to File->Create iPad version and save it as FlipSideiPad.

Then when I load the view controller, I used the following if statement to tell my program to load the iPhone interface if the device is an iPhone or to load the iPad interface if the device is an not an iPhone.

```
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideView" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;

    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];

}
else
{
    FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"iPadFlipsideView" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;

    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];

}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Where is "File->Create iPad version" on XCode 4.2?

Answer (score 0):

You need to resize the view manually...there is no such single methods for converting iphone app to ipad