# Different versions of app for different devices - iPhone to iPad

Tags: ios, xcode

I'd like to take my existing iPhone app and modify its layout/number of screens for an iPad.

I began by duplicating the Target with "Duplicate and Transition to iPad".

But I'm unsure where to go after that.  I'll need a new Storyboard and some of the functions/viewControllers/views will need to be modified.  Where/how do I do that?

All I can find are very old solutions that are no longer valid or leave too much out:

[How to convert iPhone app to iPad app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374732/how-to-convert-iphone-app-to-ipad-app/4375021)

This is the best one I've found, but again not current and still leaves a lot out:

http://innovationm.co/convert-iphone-application-to-universal-application/

I no longer see a "Universal" option.  I am guessing that selecting all of these accomplish the same thing?

[image]

Comment: There is no longer an option for "universal".

Comment: And yes there is such an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, edit your target to make sure it is set for both iPhone and iPad:

[image]

Second, using two different storyboards is unusual nowadays, but you can easily do it. In your *Info.plist* configure two entries (using Raw Keys and Values): `UIMainStoryboardFile` and `UIMainStoryboardFile~ipad`. The result is that your app will load one storyboard for an iPhone and a different storyboard for an iPad.

Note that with a newer created project that uses window scenes under iOS 13 and later, you would configure `UIApplicationSceneManifest` and `UIApplicationSceneManifest~ipad` to specify different `UISceneStoryboardFile` values.

Here's a downloadable project that demonstrates the newer structure:

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk1ch09p358universal

Comment: Thank you.  I will look at it.  I added a screenshot in the OP of where I used to see the "Universal" option.  Was it moved or do we now just select all choices to get the same result?